# A function not in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

From this equation
$$ (p^2-\alpha)\hat{f}(p)=\frac{e^{-ip\cdot y}}{p^2+\lambda}$$
where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform, $\alpha,\lambda>0$ e $y$ a fixed point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can I conclude that $f$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ if and only if it is the zero function?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Fourier transform is an isometric isomorphism on $L_2$, so you can probably just show that $\hat f$ is not in $L_2$.

Comment: You recall correctly

Comment: Pheew! However, I don't see anything like that in your conclusion. I don't even see how you come to your proposed conclusion at all. Maybe you can make that a bit clearer in your question.

Comment: @ElmarZander maybe the first part of my previous question was not very clear. The point is that I write now!

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it that way, either. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is the following: If you move $p^2-\alpha$ to the right hand side, you have
$$ \hat{f}(p)=\frac{e^{-ip\cdot y}}{(p^2+\lambda)(p^2-\alpha)}$$
If $\hat f$ is to be in $L_2$, then we need
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^3}|\hat{f}(p)|^2=\int_{\mathbb R^3} \frac{1}{(p^2+\lambda)^2(p^2-\alpha)^2}<\infty$$
The problem has spherical symmetry and you get
\begin{align}
 \int_{\mathbb R^3} \frac{1}{(p^2+\lambda)^2(p^2-\alpha)^2} dp
&= S_2 \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{r^2}{(r^2+\lambda)^2(r^2-\alpha)^2} dr\\
&= S_2 \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{r^2}{(r^2+\lambda)^2(r-\sqrt\alpha)^2
(r+\sqrt\alpha)^2} dr\\
\end{align}
where $S_2$ is the surface of the 2-sphere. 
Obviously, the integrand becomes singular at $r=\sqrt{\alpha}$, and since
\begin{align}
\int_{\sqrt\alpha-\delta}^{\sqrt\alpha+\delta} \frac{1}{(r-\sqrt\alpha)^2}
 dr=\infty
\end{align}
the whole integral cannot be finite.